# How to find all reference of a Class/Method in all source code AND referenced dll in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Using "Find All Reference", I can only find all reference in my source code. How can I find all reference in third-party referenced dll?
I'm using visual-studio 2010

Comment: If you don't have the source code for the third party DLL, I don't think you can.

Comment: 3rd party DLL and find in source code... Isn't the answer obvious?

Comment: You shouldn't be too concerned about how/where the dll uses its classes, just how you are using them

Answer (score 2):

You can find this if you install Resharper:

Expand the References and choose Find code Dependent on Module

[image]

The results then appear like:

[image]